# How to apply a JScrollPane to the text in a JLabel?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, jscrollpane

I am trying to display tables generated by my code - in HTML on a JLabel. I have added the JLabel instance to a JScrollPane object and set the vertical and horizontal scrollbars. But when the number of coloumns or rows exceeds the size, the table flows out of the list. I hoped that scrollbars could be used to navigate through the table if such a situation arises but, the scrollbars do not work for the text set to the JLabel. How do I make it scrollable?

Comment: `How do I make it scrollable?` You don't do anything special. You just create the scrollpane using the label as the parameter and add the scrollpane to the frame. Swing will do the rest. If it doesn't work the problem is with your code which you didn't post so we can't help. Post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For large content, instead of a JLabel, you can use a [JEditorPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html) which has support for HTML content. This can then be placed in a JScrollPane.

[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html) is an example using both.